Return elements from a list that match a pattern
I have a list of words as below:
STR = ['aa', 'dffg', 'aa2', 'AAA3']

I want to get a list of elements from the above list that match a string:
to_match = 'aa'

I tried the code below:
import re
[re.findall(to_match, iWord) for iWord in STR]
# [['aa'], [], ['aa'], []]

However, I wanted to get a list like ['aa',  'aa2', 'AAA3'].

Your test case should probably include 'aa' in the middle of a string, and 'aa' happening multiple times in the string. (if you're intending to use re functions)

Use re.search, with the flag re.IGNORECASE to do case-insensitive matching, as shown below.
Note that I also renamed your variables for clarity and to conform with Python naming conventions.
import re

strings = ['aa', 'dffg', 'aa2', 'AAA3']
pattern = 'aa'
matching_strings = [s for s in strings if re.search(pattern, s, re.IGNORECASE)]
print(matching_strings)
# ['aa', 'aa2', 'AAA3']

Note that re.findall returns a list, which is why the code you posted returns a list of lists. Some of these inner lists are empty, corresponding to the elements of your original list where the pattern was not found.

pattern seems to be a fixed string, not a regexp, there's little need to use re. Just use in as in the other answer.

@Barmar In the case of the OP, you are correct. In this case, the answer by Eduardo López is correct (as well as simpler and faster). However, the title of the post was about a pattern, not a fixed string. So I answered a more general question, which I think was implied. My answer works for a regex pattern too, such as pattern = r'a{1,3}\w'.

Alternative spelling: matching_strings = [*filter(re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE).search, strings)]

@Barmar The question also includes a regex attempt and was tagged regex...

@nocomment People often think they need a regexp when they actually don't. Many questions come from people who don't really know what they're doing.

Try to lower the words first:
result = [s for s in STR if to_match in s.lower()]

